# Docker dotnet run port not mapping, windows 10 host, linux container

Tags: powershell, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

I'm following a https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/docker-web-development/table-of-contents which uses the older **microsoft/aspnetcore-build** image but I'm running core 2.1 so I'm using **microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk** instead.

The command I'm running is:

> docker run -it -p 8080:5001 -v ${pwd}:/app -w "/app"
>   microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

and then once inside the TTY I do a dotnet run which gives me the following output:

> Using launch settings from /app/Properties/launchSettings.json...
>
> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>
> User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys'
>   as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
>
> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
>
> Creating key {5445e854-c1d9-4261-82f4-0fc3a7543e0a} with creation date
>   2018-12-14 10:41:13Z, activation date 2018-12-14 10:41:13Z, and
>   expiration date 2019-03-14 10:41:13Z.
>
> warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
>
> No XML encryptor configured. Key
>   {5445e854-c1d9-4261-82f4-0fc3a7543e0a} may be persisted to storage in
>   unencrypted form.
>
> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[39]
>
> Writing data to file
>   '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys/key-5445e854-c1d9-4261-82f4-0fc3a7543e0a.xml'.
>
> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>
> Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback
>   interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
>
> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>
> Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback
>   interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
>
> Hosting environment: Development
>
> Content root path: /app
>
> Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
>
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
>
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Then, when I open browser on my host and navigate to http://localhost:8080 I get a "This page isn't working" "localhost didn't send any data" " ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

I've tried a couple different port combinations too with the same result.

Can anyone spot where I went wrong? Or have any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: did you try to hit https endpoint: https://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: You are mapping `8080:5001` which is https port, you need to access https as the suggestion from Michael. If not work, can you share us detail steps to reproduce your issue? It seems to be related with the error unable to bind to 5001. Have you launch multiple apps? Try to change a new port like `5002`.

Comment: @Michael Yeah i did - same thing

Comment: @TaoZhou Im actually mapping to both http(5000) and http(5001). Have tried both http and https, slightly different effect, this time getting ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. Also tried it on port 8082

Comment: Is there any demo and detail steps to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this question still relevant for you, but I also encountered this issue and left my solution here for others. I used PowerShell with the next docker command (almost the same as your command, just used internal port **90** instead of **5000** and used **--rm** switch which will automatically remove the container when it exits):

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:90 -v ${pwd}:/app -w "/app" microsoft/dotnet /bin/bash
```

And after that, I got the interactive bash shell, and when typing `dotnet run` I got the same output as you and cannot reach my site in the container via `localhost:8080`.

I resolved it by using `UseUrls` method or `--urls` command-line argument. They (`UseUrls` method or `--urls` command-line argument) indicates the IP addresses or host addresses with ports and protocols that the server should listen on for requests. Below descriptions of solutions which worked for me:

1. Edit `CreateWebHostBuilder`method in **Program.cs** like below:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .UseUrls("http://+:90") //for your case you should use 5000 instead of 90
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

You can specify several ports if needed using the next syntax `.UseUrls("http://+:90;http://+:5000")`
With this approach, you just typed **dotnet run** in bash shell and then your container will be reachable with `localhost:8080`.

2. But with the previous approach you alter the default behavior of your source code, which you can forget and then maybe should debug and fix in the future. 
    So I prefer 2nd approach without changing the source code. After typing docker command and getting an interactive bash shell instead of just **dotnet run** type it with `--urls` argument like below (in your case use port 5000 instead of 90):

   `dotnet run --urls="http://+:90"`
3. In [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) there is also a 3rd approach where you can use `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable, but this approach didn't work for me. I used the next command (with **-e** switch):

`docker run --rm -it -p 8080:90 -v ${pwd}:/app -w "/app" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:90"   microsoft/dotnet /bin/bash`

If you type **printenv** in bash you will see that `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable was passed to the container, but for some reason **dotnet run** is ignoring it.